# organizations_url response does not include new orgs

Tags: github-api

I was recently added to an org and I can see that I am a member by clicking https://github.com/settings/organizations

But when I am making request to [https://api.github.com/users/{my_user_name}/orgs](https://api.github.com/users/%7Bmy_user_name%7D/orgs) the response does not show that organization.

Why are api response and settings page different and how can I get api response to actually show the same info as settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another API: "[Check organization membership for a user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#check-organization-membership-for-a-user)"

```
GET /orgs/:org/members/:username
```

You will want to see a 204 return code.

That is safer than a `/users/{username}/orgs` end point which does not exist (it does only appear in answers to [`/users/{username}` API queries](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users#get-a-user))